# Angular 5 with bootstrap 4 event not trigger

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an issue to when calling the bootstrap collapse event on Angular Component. Angular 5 with cli.

The Issue is the bootstrap collapse event is not picked up in the component.ts
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

the hide.bs.collapse can't trigger, the normal event in jquery like on click can be trigger.

Is the way of importing bootstrap javascript have problem or the event can't be use in angular 5?

### angular-cli (snippet)

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

### app.module.ts(whole code)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### home.component.ts(snippet)

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { Subject } from '../model/subject';
import { Education } from '../model/education';
import { Biodata } from '../model/biodata';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'] 
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  educations: Education[];
  biodata: Biodata;
  stringEdus: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeEducation();
    this.initializeBiodata();

    console.log(this.educations);
    console.log(this.biodata);

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        // do something…
        console.log('abc123');
      });
    });
  }
```

### Update

I used ngBootstrap to make the changes that I would want.

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use jQuery in Angular 2+ applications. (or there's just no need to.) Consider using Ng-Bootstrap `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples`, which is are Bootstrap 4 components written specifically for Angular.

Comment: @filipbarak hi thanks for the advice and I would like to know about why the event can't be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that event subscription in the ngAfterViewInit() method instead of ngOnInit().

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
...
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.collapse').on(...);
  }
}
```

Btw filipbarak is right. You shouldn't mix angular 2 with jquery.

Comment: I tried before it didn't work, maybe I would go for the ngBootstrap.